# What's the best way to render AJAX response into a div?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, struts

I have a web application which has a search facility. On the home page I have a search box in which the user can enter the criteria for searching and click on the Search button. After the button is clicked, we send the AJAX request to the server (Struts Action), which hits the database using DAO layer and fetches the search result.

Now I want to send this search result back to the client side and render the result in a `<div>` tag using jQuery. One page can contain 10 results. If the user clicks on 'next page' we want to show another 10 records.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: What have you done so far? There are a lot of requirements in your question, which parts have you already implemented and which parts are you having the problems with?

Comment: Not started with the code as of now.But i want to understand which format i should send data from server to client?Json or anything else?And how to render it on client side?I dont want to use document.getElementById("resultDiv").innerHtml = ".." on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that probably the best method is to use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) jQuery method just to serve search results and manipulate via AJAX the content of the results div; then you can act on to the elements within the container div with [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, in order to trigger the "go to the next page" event, for example. In this way you only need the container div and you're free to build the results data elsewhere, using all the serverside languages that you need.

Comment: Thanks bobighorus! How do you I send my result to client side?Should I send it using JSON?

Comment: I suggest to build an external HTML page and then load it with .load() method. So you can build this page with PHP, JSON and so on... If you found this answer helpful, please check and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

The 'next' page feature is commonly referred to as Pagination. Every programming language has several examples of this throughout Google. Just do a quick search on Pagination + your programming language.

**Rest of example assumes use of PHP to handle backend requests**

with jQuery and Ajax, we handle the response in the success parameter, example to follow:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'whatever.php'
  data: 'mystring='+mystring,
  success: function(data){
    $("#myElement").html(data);
  }
});
```

*data* is returned as an object containing all information returned by whatever.php. However you structure your return of your results in your whatever.php file is how your data will be structured and presented and placed into your element with an id="myElement".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know jquery provides an autocomplete control to develop search facility in web application.

You can visit

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

for more details

Thanks,
Vijay satlawar

Comment: While you are right and it does, this isn't really appropriate for what the user is asking.